# How to adjust size of the displayed image in rhandsontable?

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I am trying to display images in a rhandsontable. The images are of various sizes. I would like to normalize the display size of the images to a single size. In this regard, I need help with how to adjust the display size of the image in a rhandsontable.

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(
  comments = c(
    "I would rate it &#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2606;",
    "This is the book about JavaScript"
  ), 
  cover = c(
    "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bRhyVTVGL._SL50_.jpg",
    "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51gdVAEfPUL._SL50_.jpg",
 ),
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

rhandsontable(DF, allowedTags = "<em><b><strong><a><big>", 
              width = 800, height = 450, rowHeaders = FALSE) %>%
  hot_cols(colWidths = c(200, 80)) %>%
  hot_col(1, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer")) %>%
  hot_col(2, renderer = "
    function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      var escaped = Handsontable.helper.stringify(value),
        img;
  
      if (escaped.indexOf('http') === 0) {
        img = document.createElement('IMG');
        img.src = value;
  
        Handsontable.dom.addEvent(img, 'mousedown', function (e){
          e.preventDefault(); // prevent selection quirk
        });
  
        Handsontable.dom.empty(td);
        td.appendChild(img);
      }
      else {
        // render as text
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
      }
  
      return td;
    }")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the width and height **(img.style.width = '80px'; img.style.height = '80px';)** to the image property solved the issue.

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(
  comments = c(
    "I would rate it &#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2606;",
    "This is the book about JavaScript"
  ), 
  cover = c(
    "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bRhyVTVGL._SL50_.jpg",
    "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51gdVAEfPUL._SL50_.jpg",
 ),
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

rhandsontable(DF, allowedTags = "<em><b><strong><a><big>", 
              width = 800, height = 450, rowHeaders = FALSE) %>%
  hot_cols(colWidths = c(200, 80)) %>%
  hot_col(1, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer")) %>%
  hot_col(2, renderer = "
    function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      var escaped = Handsontable.helper.stringify(value),
        img;
  
      if (escaped.indexOf('http') === 0) {
        img = document.createElement('IMG');
        img.src = value; img.style.width = '80px'; img.style.height = '80px';
  
        Handsontable.dom.addEvent(img, 'mousedown', function (e){
          e.preventDefault(); // prevent selection quirk
        });
  
        Handsontable.dom.empty(td);
        td.appendChild(img);
      }
      else {
        // render as text
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
      }
  
      return td;
    }")
```